# How to load query Result to a IList<T>

Tags: c#, list

I have a `IList<T>`

```
IList<Student> studsList = new IList<Student>();
```

How to load `name` and `age` properties  from this query to my `studsList`?

```
   using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(querySQL, connection))

   {
      connection.Open();
      string query = "SELECT name, age FROM Student";
      using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(querySQL, connection)) {
          using(OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter()) {
              oracleDataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;                  
              command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              //What to do here? 
          }

      }
```

Comment: Why would you care about names or age of [studs](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stud)? They are "basically a badass" already :) (really love when one comes up with creative short names... Shortening assembly is the best so far, but your one is nice).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov hahah I always use fictive names to illustrate my problem , hahahah

Comment: @napi15 did you succeed using dapper ? did you have difficulties ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`, you are saying "I don't expect results". If you want to see the results, you'll need to use `ExecuteReader`, which returns an `IDataReader` API that allows you to loop over the rows in a forwards direction using `.Read()`. Then, per row you have access to a range of APIs for accessing columns, including via the indexer (`[]`), or `GetValue` or `GetValues` or typed access methods (`GetString`, `GetInt32`, etc).

Or more simply - use a tool like dapper!

```
var students = connection.Query<Student>(query);
```

this deals with:

- connection lifetime (opening, etc)
- creating the command
- parameterization (not shown in this example, but really easy)
- executing the command
- processing the reader
- parsing the contents of each row into the `T` (`Student` in this case)
- closing everything down correctly

For a parameterized example:

```
var region = "North";
var students = connection.Query<Student>(
    "select * from Students where Region=@region", new { region });
```

(you might need to use `$region` or `:region` depending on your ADO.NET provider)

Comment: Dapper seems to be a powerful wrapper that could solve my problems and issues once for all , do you have an idea if it's free and allowed to use in commercial use?

Comment: @napi15, https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/License.txt - Apache, so yes.

Comment: @napi15 yes, we make it available for free and the license is very permissive; if it somehow isn't permissive enough (which I would struggle to see): log an issue or email us :)

Comment: I can't wait to propose this wrapper to the seniors in my team as I'm a junior and not allowed to call shots and they need to see the security perspective. But , just by looking at the example page I can tell it's what I'm looking for since forever , a good wrapper where I could optimize my models and queries in a human way . Thanks !!!

Comment: @napi15 if they have any questions in that they can feel free to email me (I'm the primary author/maintainer) - but: making it easy for folks to correctly parameterize SQL to *improve* security was one of our primary goals. Another was performance - it is the data tool used by about 95% of the code here at Stack Overflow. Oh, btw: it also does some really really cool things with `in` queries, making it trivially easy to fetch multiple rows - `where x.Id in @ids` with `new { ids = someListOrArrayOfIntegers }` does everything you'd want.